# DataFrame to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, dataframe

```
with open('configLocalDS3.json') as f:
    conf = json.load(f)

    conn_str ='postgresql://%s:%s@localhost:5432/%s'%(conf["user"], 
    conf["passw"],conf["database"])
    engine = create_engine(conn_str, echo='debug')

    if not engine.has_table("table"):
        df_crimes.to_sql(name='table',index=True, 
        index_label='index',con=engine,if_exists='replace')
    else:
        print("table already exists")

    #Daten aus der Datenbank ausgeben

    with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
        data = pd.read_sql_table('table',conn)
```

[image]

It does not work to write the data from the DataFrame to SQL; I don't get results by reading the SQL table.

Comment: what part of your code doesn't work?

Comment: I dindt get any Results by reading -->data = pd.read_sql_table('table',conn)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you used context manager here for sqlalchemy engine connect, as pandas sql read can be done inline like:

```
engine = create_engine(conn_str, echo='debug')
data = pd.read_sql_table('table', engine)
```